# Puppet installation error

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, puppetmaster

I am trying to install puppet enterprise for the first time, and following this documentation: https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2019.0/installing_pe.html

I have downloaded the file and executed it locally in what is going to be the master server (Ubuntu 18.04).

When I try to install, I see a few errors and the installer just stops.

Here are the errors:

`Warning: Error connecting to puppet on 8081 at route /pdb/query/v4, error message received was 'Failed to open TCP connection to puppet.my.tld:8140 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "puppet.my.tld" port 8140)'. Failing over to the next PuppetDB server_url in the 'server_urls' list`

Also:

`[Error]: Failed to apply catalog: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:4433 (Invalid argument - connect(2) for "puppet" port 4433)`

There are also other errors and warnings in between, but apparently there seems to be something wrong with connecting to the host, or with some part of the certificate creation.

When the setup starts, I am asked to edit a configuration file. I have tried only placing in a password, also adding my fqdn to cert_altnames, adding that fqdn also to console and master host, but same errors happen. Either not being able to connect or not being able to generate certificates.

The errors mentioned above change depending on whether I have added the FQDN or not (it mentions puppet:8140 instead of my domain).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which server is `puppet.my.tld`? Can you resolve its address and connect to it?

Comment: Yes I can resolve it's address from within and outside the machine. @MichaelHampton please remove that domain from your comment, I forgot to clean that from my post. that server is the master server I am trying to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when installing PE 2021.7.3 on a ubuntu 20.04 machine, I resolved this issue by setting the umask to 0022 from 0027.